# python polars: new column based on condition/comparison of two existing columns

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to create a new column in Polars data frame based on comparison of two existing columns:

```
import polars as pl
data = {"a": [2, 30], "b": [20, 3]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

df
Out[4]:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 20  │
│ 30  ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

When I do:

```
df.with_columns(pl.map(["a", "b"], lambda s: "+" if s[0] < s[1] else "-").alias("strand"))
```

I am getting an error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'python apply failed: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Hint: use '&' or '|' to chain Series boolean results together, not and/or; to check if a Series contains any values, use 'is_empty()'', src/lazy/apply.rs:185:19
```

I am able to create a boolean column:

```
df.with_columns(pl.map(["a", "b"], lambda s: s[0] < s[1] ).alias("strand"))
```

so with extra steps I should get the column with the desired "+" and "-", but is there some simpler way?

Thank you for your help

DK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polars expressions e.g. [`when/then/otherwise`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html)

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("a") < pl.col("b")).then("+").otherwise("-")
     .alias("strand")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   | b   | strand │
│ --- | --- | ---    │
│ i64 | i64 | str    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 2   | 20  | +      │
│ 30  | 3   | -      │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘
```

or [`.map_dict`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html#polars.Expr.map_dict)

```
df.with_columns(
   (pl.col("a") < pl.col("b"))
   .map_dict({True: "+", False: "-"})
   .alias("strand")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   | b   | strand │
│ --- | --- | ---    │
│ i64 | i64 | str    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 2   | 20  | +      │
│ 30  | 3   | -      │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! This (pl.when) does work like a charm. I have a follow up question about swapping values between a and b columns (a should have always lower value) but I  should experiment first

Comment: @darked89 You may be looking for [`pl.min`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.min.html#polars-min)